# How can I change button color,glyphicon and text on clicking it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

It works normally when I toggle button and it changes `glyphicons`. But i want also change text and color as well.Here is my code

Html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
        &nbsp;Add
</button>
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(':button').click(function(){
     $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus').toggleClass('glyphicon-ok');
});
```

try this one doesn't help me - `removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-danger').text('chosen')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(':button').click(function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-ok').toggleClass('btn-primary btn-danger' );
    });
```

The toggleClass function can accept 2 parameters. If passed 2 params, it will toggle one off and one on depending on which class is currently applied to the element.

Comment: You've made a typo with your quotes

Comment: May be you have the solution, but could you explain you code? thank you

Comment: You toggle the button primary and danger classes on the `i`

Comment: Added an explanation.

Comment: And that is not what the 2nd parameter does. the 2nd parameter can only be true/false